# ELMAH logging at one place in Azure multiple web role instances environment

Tags: azure, elmah, webrole

Is there a way to configure ELMAH to write logs in Azure blob so that logging from multiple instances can be monitored at one place? For example, configuring ELMAH to write to blobs instead of writing to files in the file system.

I guess It can be done using SQL but I am trying to avoid one more additional component.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

[Elmah On Azure Table Storage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.AzureTableStorage/0.5.2)

or this:

[Elmah with Windows Azure Table Storage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ELMAH.Tables)

Both use Table storage versus Blob.  We have been using the latter for a couple of years now and it works great.